# jQuery .find() not working correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]

I'm trying to allow some text of `<p>` (the comment) to be editable when the user clicks on 'Edit'.

```
function editComment(commentid,replyid){

   $('#comment'+commentid).find('.comment-text').attr("contenteditable='true'");

}
```

However this is giving me an error (undefined) and I'm not sure why, as `.comment-text` is a child of `#comment88`? I'm probably missing something really simple

Comment: Is `commentid` a string?

Comment: Your code works fine for me, except you're misusing `attr`. When attempting to set an attribute value, it takes two arguments: `attr(name, value)`. I stuck it in a pen for you: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vOoBXL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your HTML DOM and jQuery looks fine and legit, however the attr function would cause a trouble. I would suggest that you apply the style using this,

```
$('#comment'+commentid).find('.comment-text').attr("contenteditable", true);
```

This will apply the attribute to your element.

**Description**: When you use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) function to add or update the attribute value, you pass two parameters. One as a key and second as the value for that attribute (key). If you pass only one, it will return that attribute's value. This is the problem that gets raised in your case, the find function is working, but in the final function, instead of applying that attribute it returns the value (false IMO).

Comment: @frosty, undefined, then the problem will be with the `commentid` variable. It may be having a value that causes the element to not be found.